# Is it possible to set up PHP.ini to use the Yahoo Mail or Gmail smtp server?

Tags: php, email

Basically, every answer to this question that I have found recommends you download some external library. I don't need all the extra functionality when sending mails, all I want to do is set up php.ini to use Yahoo's servers, so I can use the mail() function. Is this even possible? And if not, what is the most lightweight no-frills way to use Yahoo Mail's smtp server? I would prefer it to be a single file if possible.

Comment: If you want a good mail client use [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/introduction.html). If you want really want a legacy style one class lib use [PHPmailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mail()` function sends the email through unix [`sendmail`](http://www.sendmail.org/~ca/email/man/sendmail.html) command or any other compatible MTA like [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/sendmail.1.html) (Ubuntu's default MTA) or [exim](http://www.exim.org/).

If you simply want to send an email through STMP, I recommend you using a 3th party library like [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/). Otherwise you will need to install and configure an MTA in your server.